# NetBeans EE includes Java EE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, sdk, java-7

I'm fairly new to Java and I've been working on Java SE JDK 7 + Eclipse for Java. 
If I install NetBeans for Java EE, do I have to install Java EE 7 SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [link](http://wiki.netbeans.org/JavaEE7), JEE7 is partially supported and it will be feature complete with Netbeans 8. Also, I have tried myself to setup Tomcat 8.0(partial support for JEE7) to work with Netbeans 7.3.1, it doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: looks like [Netbeans 7.3.1 for Java EE](http://wiki.netbeans.org/JavaEE7NetBeans731) got everything I need...

Answer (score 1):

No. Java EE 7 is a specification, which is implemented by an Java EE application server. So if you use the bundled GlassFish, you'll have everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

no, It Will Work With The Old One,
just Go To The command line and type

```
javac -version
```

and if u found it so it will working With NetBeans Good